# Window resize not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, resize, loading

My background image loads blocky for some reason (i.e., the center doesn't load horizontally), but after any tiny window resize it snaps into full form. I wanted to add a small bit of Javascript to adjust the window size by 1 pixel to remedy this. Unfortunately, I'm getting no results with the below code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        window.resizeTo(window.outerHeight, window.outerWidth + 1);
    }
</script>
```

Anyone have any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: you forgot to add a ) at the end to close the ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to close the DOM ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.resizeTo(window.outerHeight, window.outerWidth + 1);
}); // <-- Here
```

Comment: Thanks -- I copied it in without the closing brackets somehow. But the problem persists with the closing brackets. Here's it in real-time, with resizeTo specific pixels:

http://www.lncoffline.com/Thanksgiving/index.html